# Combining SurfaceView with other Views such as TextView and Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, opengl-es, surfaceview

I'm totally new to android programming (just did some tutorials/read the dev guides etc.) and as every newbie I want to do a useless game :-).

Currently I'm struggling with the layout of different views. Similar to the example I've made a class which extends a `SurfaceView` and put that into a `FrameLayout`. Around this `SurfaceView` I want to have other View's like `Buttons` & `TextViews`.
Something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| TextView | SurfaceView           | TextView |
|          |                       |          |
------------                       ------------
|          |                       | TextView |
|          |                       |          |
|          |                       ------------
|          |                       | TextView |
|          |                       |          |
|          |                       ------------
|          |                       |          |
|          |                       |          |
-----------------------------------------------
| Button                             Button   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I've managed to do something like this with a `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayouts` (sticking the `TextViews` at the edges of the screen) but I'd like to better control the size of the `SurfaceView` as it should be a multiple in width and height of the object(s) I'll be drawing in it. I've tried setting `layout_width` and `layout_height` to some dp values but when I start painting at 0,0 it's still at the very top-left corner (where the `TextView` is..).

So, what's the best practice to achieve a layout as above? Using what layout? Or should I better draw my text inside the `draw()` function of my `SurfaceView` instead?

Comment: You should post your xml to give people a better clue of thwat the issue might be.

Answer (score 6):

Layouts are the right way to combine OpengGL content with buttons, labels and other type of view objects. You can combine layouts inside other layouts... so you may build your screen step by step combining Linear Layouts or whatever you prefer.

For example, you can use a Relative layout to setup the buttons (b1, b2) and the rest of the screen:

```
+-----------+
|  Zone 1   |
+-----+-----+
| b1  | b2  |
+-----+-----+
```

Then inside Zone 1, you can use a Horizontal Linear Layout for the 3 main columns

```
+----+----+----+
| c1 | c2 | c3 |
+----+----+----+
```

Inside of c2 you can place the SurfaceView, and in c1 the text label

Inside c3 will be a new Vertical Linear layout to display the text labels.

```
+----+
| t1 |
+----+
| t2 |
+----+
| t3 |
+----+
```